# bash script run Java app which uses Scanner

Tags: java, bash

Have a shell script which compiles/executes multiple Java applications and captures the output of each app. to a file.
The script was working fine until I ran into a series of applications which require an input via the Scanner class in Java.

One thing I thought about was to grep the .java file for keyword "Scanner" and skip those files.

Any other suggestions on how to overcome this problem using plain ole shell script? The source can't be modified.

(no ant, maven or other build managers please)

Comment: You should send the relevant input via stdin.

Comment: how would you know the input type? (int, String, boolean, byte) ...every app is designed differently.

Comment: If you don't know what input your app expects, you have no hope of making it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can override Scanner with a custom implementation that doesn't build.  Example:

Directory Structure:

```
/Tester.java
/java/util/Scanner.java
```

Then, inside `Tester.java` you have:

```
import java.util.Scanner:

class Tester {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }
}
```

And inside `Scanner.java` you have:

```
I'm Broken!
```

Of course "I'm Broken!" will not compile so your program will break.  So when you compile you will end up with this error:

```
./java/util/Scanner.java:1: error: unclosed character literal
I'm Broken!
 ^
Tester.java:1: error: cannot access Scanner
import java.util.Scanner;
                ^
  bad source file: ./java/util/Scanner.java
    file does not contain class java.util.Scanner
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
```